# TeamCity: Backing up data via command line

Tags: command-line, teamcity

I want to write a PowerShell script to regularly automate back-ups of the following:

[image]

According to TeamCity's 9.x documentation, these are the command-line options for specifying what to back up:

[image]

I could use `-C` ("includes build configurations settings") and `-U` ("includes supplementary (plugins') data"), but that will leave out: Server settings, project configurations, and plugins.

I could simply run the `maintainDB.cmd backup` command without specifying any additional options, but that will back up the database too, which is not what I want.

How can I back up only the 1) server settings, 2) project and build configurations, 3) plugins, as well as 4) supplementary data via the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted TeamCity Support for an answer and received the following reply:

> Hello,
>
> Actually, -C option in the command line is the same as "server
>   settings, projects and builds configurations, plugins" in the UI.
>
> `How can I back up only the 1) server settings, 2) project and build
>   configurations, 3) plugins, as well as 4) supplementary data via the
>   command line?`
>
> -C -U is the combination.